# How to add the month in a gannt chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

I made a gannt chart with weeks but on tops of the weeks I would like to add the respective month (for example w. 31 to 34 is August) How can I do that?

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\title{Gantt Charts with the pgfgantt Package}
\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}{31}{53}
  \gantttitle{2016}{22} \\
  \gantttitlelist{31,...,52}{1} \\
  \ganttgroup{Problem formulation}{31}{31} \\
  \ganttbar{Literature review}{32}{35} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar{Data collection}{36}{39} \ganttnewline

  \ganttlinkedbar{Value chain analysis}{40}{43}
  \ganttnewline
  \ganttlinkedbar{Strategic framework}{44}{48}
\ganttnewline 
  \ganttlinkedbar{Inspect report and wrap up}{49}{52}
 \ganttnewline
 \ganttmilestone{Hand-in}{52} 
 \ganttlink{elem5}{elem6}
   % \ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add more \gantttitle commands:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\title{Gantt Charts with the pgfgantt Package}
\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}{31}{53}
  \gantttitle{2016}{22} \\
  \gantttitle[title/.style={draw=none,}]{}{3}
  \gantttitle{August}{4}
  \gantttitle{September}{4}\\
  \gantttitlelist{31,...,52}{1} \\
  \ganttgroup{Problem formulation}{31}{31} \\
  \ganttbar{Literature review}{32}{35} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar{Data collection}{36}{39} \ganttnewline

  \ganttlinkedbar{Value chain analysis}{40}{43}
  \ganttnewline
  \ganttlinkedbar{Strategic framework}{44}{48}
\ganttnewline
  \ganttlinkedbar{Inspect report and wrap up}{49}{52}
 \ganttnewline
 \ganttmilestone{Hand-in}{52}
 \ganttlink{elem5}{elem6}
   % \ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

[image]